# Limit to number of requests to Microsoft Face API

Tags: azure-cognitive-services

Does anyone know if the "Out of call volume quota" is exclusively for free trial user and if we subscribe to the monthly plan, there will be no limit to the number of calls to Microsoft Face API?
  I would also like to know since the API can take 10 requests per second from a paid key, does that mean by requesting with different processes simultaneously, the total process time can be shortened?

Thank you

Comment: related?: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/ai-services/computer-vision/identity-quotas-limits

Answer (score 1):

From the [pricing page](https://www.microsoft.com/cognitive-services/en-us/pricing) the limit for the free trial is 30,000 API calls a month and that's removed on the paid tier. The standard paid tier has a max throughput of 10 transactions per second, for example that could come for example from multiple apps all submitting calls at the same time. If you need higher volume please reach out to the team via the *contact us* link at the bottom of the page on [www.microsoft.com/cognitive](https://www.microsoft.com/cognitive-services/)

Comment: Ryan (@ryan) please see my answer below. If you have an alternate view - that it is actually possible to increase the limit - I would be delighted to hear from you.

Answer (score 1):

After reading Ryan's answer I tried to determine from Microsoft how much it would cost to increase the transaction limit.

As of today, Microsoft Inside Sales confirmed that it is not possible.

We are stymied and so are considering other Cloud services that have a higher or no rate limit, such as Kairos (https://www.kairos.com/pricing)